# Recursive Fibonacci Sequence print out the list

Tags: java, recursion, computer-science, fibonacci

I have the follow code for a recursive Fibonacci Sequence

```
    if (term < 2){
        System.out.print("1 ");
        return 1;
    } 
        int results = fibonacci(term - 1) + fibonacci(term - 2);
        System.out.print(results + " ");

        return results;
```

The output I get is

What term would you like to do the Fibonacci Sequence up to: 4

1 1 2 1 3 1 1 2 5 The 4th is 5

How do I make it so it prints

1 1 2 3 The 4th is 5

Answer (score 1):

Use tail recursion.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("The 10th is: " + fibonnaci(10));
  }

  public static int fibonnaci(int number) {
     return fibonnaciHelper(number, 1, 1);
  }

  public static int fibonnaciHelper(int term, int lower, int higher) {
      if (term < 2){
          return higher;

      } 

      System.out.print(higher + " ");
      int results = fibonnaciHelper(term - 1, higher, higher + lower);
      return results;
  }
```

Comment: I understand how your program work, however, I would I get the print out of 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 ... with the recursion program that I wrote.

Comment: @Shi_No_Tenshi try System.out.println(fibnnoaci(6));

Comment: @Shi_No_Tenshi I don't understand your question

Comment: @Shi_No_Tenshi You can't. It's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Iterative fibionacci sequence - had it lying about somewhere

```
public static int fib(int n) {
            int prev1=0, prev2=1;
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                int savePrev1 = prev1;
                prev1 = prev2;
                prev2 = savePrev1 + prev2;
            }
            return prev1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```
public void fib(int n){
    if(n==0)
        System.out.println(1);

    else System.out.println(fib(1,n,0,1);
}

private int fib(int iteration, int limit, int n0, int n1){
    if(iteration==limit)
         return(n0+n1);

    fib(++iteration,limit,n1,(n0+n1));
}
```